# Pygame LEVEL changing

Tags: python, pygame

I need to make a level changing, but I can't get it working. I'm trying to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573533/pygame-change-level-level-made-of-list).

When I try to start I get no level at all. My code:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python

import pygame
from pygame import *
#import pyganim

#=========Display======#
WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30


#=========Game main==#
def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    currentLevel = 0

    up = down = left = right = running = False


    bg = Surface((32,32))
    #bg = pygame.image.load('BG\BGL1.png').convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 55)




    levels = [[
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS",
        "PPPPPPPPPSSSSSSS          ",
        " ",
        "                                                     

        ],
        [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPP"
        ]]


        # Level Generating code 
    def load_level(level):
        platforms = []
        x = y = 0
        for row in levels:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    p = Platform(x, y)
                    platforms.append(p)
                    entities.add(p)
                if col == "E":
                    e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                    platforms.append(e)
                    entities.add(e)
                if col == "G":
                    g = Platform1(x, y)
                    platforms.append(g)
                    entities.add(g)
                if col == "A":
                    a = Stone(x, y)
                    platforms.append(a)
                    entities.add(a)
                if col == "S":
                    s = Stone0(x, y)
                    platforms.append(s)
                    entities.add(s)
                if col == "H":
                    h = HalfPlaform0(x, y)
                    platforms.append(h)
                    entities.add(h)
                if col == "B":
                    b = StoneBack(x, y)
                    entities.add(b)
                if col == "T":
                    t = Bridge(x,y)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 0
        return platforms, entities

    platforms, entities = load_level(currentLevel)
    load_level(currentLevel)




    total_levels_width  = len(levels[0])*32
    total_levels_height = len(levels)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_levels_width, total_levels_height)
    entities.add(player)



    while 1:

        load_level(currentLevel)
        timer.tick(60)


        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit("QUIT")
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit("ESCAPE")
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_l:
                currentLevel += 1
                load_level(currentLevel)
                print(level)

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False







        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))


        ##Update player, draw everything else##
        ###THE PROBLEM IS HERE I THINK###

        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        '''
        BegimoAnim.anchor(anchorPoint = 'east')
        BegimoAnim.blit(screen, (player))
        '''


        camera.update(player)
        pygame.display.update()
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)





class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           ## stop scrolling at the left edge##
    #l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   ## stop scrolling at the right edge##
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) ## stop scrolling at the bottom##
    t = min(0, t)                           ## stop scrolling at the top##
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)


#============PLAYER===============#
right_standing = pygame.image.load('PlayerModels\Sprites\PlayerStill2.gif')
left_standing = pygame.transform.flip(right_standing, True, False)
animTypes = 'right_walk'.split()

'''
BegimoAnim = pyganim.PygAnimation([
    ('PlayerModels\Sprites\Player_right_walk1.gif', 0.2,),
    ('PlayerModels\Sprites\Player_right_walk2.gif', 0.2,),
                                    ])
'''

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface = right_standing
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        a = 0
        #BegimoAnim.blit(screen, (player))
        if up:
            # Pasokti tik ant zemes
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 7
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -5
            self.image = left_standing
        if right:
            self.xvel = 5
            self.image = right_standing




            #BegimoAnim.play()

        if not self.onGround:
            # gravitacija + acceleracija
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # Max kritimo greitis
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # Prieaugis X direkcijoje
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # daryti X axis collision
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # Prieaugis Y direkcijoje
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # Ar ore?
        self.onGround = False;
        # daryti Y axis collision
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)



    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        level = 0
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    currentLevel += 1
                    walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)
                    print(level)
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left

                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right

                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

#=========Platforms, ground
class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface =  pygame.image.load("GroundModels\Ground0.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class Platform1(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface =  pygame.image.load("GroundModels\Ground.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass
#================stone
class Stone(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface = pygame.image.load("GroundModels\Stone.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class Stone0(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface = pygame.image.load("GroundModels\Stone0.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class StoneBack(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface = pygame.image.load("GroundModels\Stone.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)


class Bridge(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)

    def update(self):
        pass
#=================pusblokis zeme
class HalfPlaform0(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface =  pygame.image.load("GroundModels\HalfGround0.png").convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y + 16, 32, 16)


    def update(self):
        pass


class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please, just only post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `load_level` function takes a `level` parameter, but it never uses it anywhere.

Instead, it does:

```
def load_level(level):
    # ...
    for row in levels:
        for col in row:
```

Now, `levels` is a list of levels, which are a list of rows, which are a string of columns.

But you're doing `for row in levels`, meaning that you're naming each level a `row`, and then `for col in row` names each row within that a level a column, and a whole row is never going to be `== "E"` or any of the other things you check. So you get back an empty list of platforms and an empty list of entities.

What you probably wanted was:

```
def load_level(level):
    # ...
    for row in levels[level]:
```

---

After you fix this: I don't think you want to leave the sprite group `entities` full of level 1's sprites, and then add level 2's sprites, then level 3's, and so on, without ever clearing them out.

But that's exactly what you're doing. In `main`, you assign `entities` to an empty group. Then, inside `load_level`, you just call `add` on that `entities` from the outer function. And then you return that same `entities`, which `main` assigns to `entities`, which it already was.

I think you want to create a new `entities` sprite group inside `load_level`, just as you create a new `platforms` list. (And if not, you definitely don't want the misleading code that modifies the outer variable then returns its value just to reassign it to the same variable… Do one or the other, not both.)

Comment: hmm thanks I found that too, but I now when I load level both levels are loaded and then I get some lag. Any fixes?

Comment: @Justasmig: Are you sure both levels are loaded? You definitely load the first level 3 times, which is a lot of wasted effort. Also, as I mentioned, each time you load a level, you add its sprites onto the existing ones instead of replacing the existing ones. And I'm willing to bet there are other bugs, but there's far too much code to try to find them all and then guess which one you're seeing first. If you have a new question, create a new question, and try to write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that question instead of dumping everything.

Comment: How I should fix the first level loading 3 times? I now wanted to post a question about optimisations but I think it's because my code do this... And yeah I think I really should try to write minimal and complete.

Comment: @Justasmig: Well, for one thing, why are you calling `loadLevels` twice in a row? Just don't do that. And then, later on, you call `loadLevels` at the start of the loop. If you're going to call it then, why did you need to call it before? You need to figure out where the right place is, and only do it there, not all over the place.

Comment: @Justasmig: I suspect doing it inside the loop, once/frame, may be related to your performance problem… but without any testing, it's hard to do more than guess.

Comment: just found that and fixed that   EDIT no I didn't found second loadlevels :/ I'm gonna update my code in this post

Comment: If You wanna test I can give You my whole project folder ( first I'm going to translate comments). P.S. THANKS FOR HELPING MEE :))

Comment: @Justasmig: Don't update your question. If anyone else has the same problem as you, the original question and the answer that goes with it will help them. If you change it into a different question—especially by removing the problem from it—it helps no one. If you have a more complete answer than mine, just add a new answer to the question. (You can answer your own questions.) If you have a followup question, create a new question.

Comment: @Justasmig: Sorry, I can't test and debug your code for you; I don't even have a working SDL/PyGame setup on this machine.

Comment: hmm I got problems with changing levels on collision. Can anybody help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716693/pygame-level-changing-on-collision